# Navegação e sticky nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

estou a tentar fazer com que a minha navbar seja sticky quando chega à secção depois do header, mas não estou a conseguir, já pesquisei várias maneiras, mas a navbar fica muito bugada...

Primeiro problema:
Ao tentar fazer sticky nav, a nav fica bugada...

Segundo problema:
Estava também a tentar adicionar sombra à navbar mas não aparece qualquer sombra. E quando reduzo o tamanho do ecra o slider fica em cima da navbar, mesmo a navbar tendo 5000 de index.

HTML da navbar:

```
<div class="row">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">


          <ul class="menu menu-js">

            <li><a href="#search"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong icon-small clearfix"></i>SEARCH</a></li>

            <li><a href="#top_artists"><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small clearfix"></i>TOP ARTISTS</a></li>

            <li><a href="#about_us"><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small clearfix"></i>ABOUT US</a></li>

            <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="ion-ios-telephone icon-small clearfix"></i>CONTACTS</a></li>

            <li><a href=""><i class="ion-ios-unlocked icon-small clearfix"></i>SETTINGS</a><ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#openModal">REGISTER</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>






            <!------- Mobile navi button ----->
            <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
        </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS da nav:

/*FIRST NAVI*/

```
.sticky .menu,
.menu > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    /* impede que os menus quebrem */
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.1%;
    transform: translateY(-5%);
    float:  left;
    width: 210px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 5%;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .menu {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .menu > li {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .menu > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 5%;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.sticky .menu>li>a {
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #74C8D2;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5000;
}

//*.menu>li>a:hover {
//    color: #fff;
//    background-color: #74C8D2;
//    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
/*/



/* shadow */
/*.menu>li>a::after,
.menu>li>a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li>a::after {
    top: 100%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -50%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a::before {
    top: -5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 150%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a:hover::after,
.menu>ul>li>a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
} */




/* menu icon */
.sticky .menu>li>a>i {
    vertical-align: middle;
}



/* submenu */
.sticky .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    /* transition: all .5s ease-in-out;*/
}

/* .menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
} */


.sticky .sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sticky .sub-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #74C8D2;
}

/*.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
    background: #74C8D2;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
} */
```

O JS que estou a usar para fazer o sticky:

```
/*Sticky nav*/
    $('.js--section-search').waypoint(function(direction) {
       if (direction == "down") {
            $('navbar').addClass('sticky');   
       } else {
            $('navbar').removeClass('sticky');
       }                               
    }, {
        offset: '60px;'
    });
```

Comment: Vc está utilizando algum framework Css?

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando uma grid

Answer (score 1):

Eu Criei um usando Bootstrap dessa maneira,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){     
var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){   
    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();         
     if(scrollPos >= navOffset){        
        jQuery("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top minhaClasse"); 
     }else{             
         jQuery("nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top minhaClasse");   
   }
  });
});
```

Se você usar a estrutura padrão do boostrap ele vem com as classes navbar-fixed-top única coisa que é preciso fazer o calculo do scroll de quando o menu chegar na borda do navegador receber essa classe.

https://www.oxyhospedagem.com.br da uma conferida como ficou